# Requirements for client-server model over the internet

Tags: c#, android, sockets, tcp

For a college project, I am hoping to develop a client/server model in C# that will allow the client to stream audio and video from the server. (Android device, streaming from PC)

I understand using tcp sockets and ports, I should be able to (eventually) achieve this over the internet using port forwarding on my router.

Is this possible without port forwarding? How could I, say, have someone install a app on their PC in their phone, and have them communicate? What is required to do so?

I have a long way to go with my studies before I attempt this but I was just hoping for some guidance on what is involved.

Comment: Your question appears to be based on port forwarding not a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

you need to have static ip , given by your ISP and just deploy on your IIS or you can use Azure for that - i guess it is just for project

asp.net WebApi has thhe capability to stream data